# ClickOnce Improperly Formattet

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce, .net-standard

Error Message:

> Cannot continue. The application is improperly formatted. Contact the
>   application publisher for assistance.

Nothing else shown. "Details-Button" is disabled.
No Log created when enabling ClickOnce Logging (could also be that I did that wrong)

[Project Location](https://github.com/Drachenhorn-Team/Drachenhorn)

I have tried some of the Solutions I found.
Even tried completely reconstructing the entire Project (because I changed from Nuget "packages.config" to PackageReference)

Does anyone have any Idea, how to fix this?

Screenshot (Sorry it's in German):
[image]

**Update**
When trying to install on another PC (Win7) this Error Message is shown:

```
INFO ZUR PLATTFORMVERSION
Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
System.Deployment.dll       : 4.7.3190.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_C
clr.dll             : 4.7.3190.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_C
dfdll.dll           : 4.7.3190.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_C
dfshim.dll          : 4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000)

QUELLEN
    Bereitstellungs-URL: file:///D:/Users/.../Desktop/....dsac
    Bereitstellungsanbieter-URL: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Drachenhorn-Team/Drachenhorn/publish/Drachenhorn.Desktop.application

FEHLERZUSAMMENFASSUNG
    Es folgt eine Zusammenfassung der Fehler. Details zu diesen Fehlern werden später im Protokoll aufgelistet.
    * Die Aktivierung von D:\Users\Daniel Nietfeld\Desktop\Günther.dsac führte zu einer Ausnahme. Folgende Fehlermeldungen wurden entdeckt:
      + Ausnahme beim Lesen des Manifests aus 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Drachenhorn-Team/Drachenhorn/publish/Application%20Files/Drachenhorn.Desktop_0_0_10_42/Drachenhorn.Desktop.exe.manifest': Das Manifest ist möglicherweise ungültig, oder die Datei konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
    + Das Analysieren und die DOM-Erstellung des Manifestes führten zu einem Fehler. Folgende Fehler wurden beim Analysieren protokolliert: 
        -HRESULT:   0x80070c81
         Anfangszeile:  0
         Anfangsspalte:     0
         Hostdatei:     
    + Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80070C81

FEHLERZUSAMMENFASSUNG FÜR DIE SPEICHERTRANSAKTION DER KOMPONENTE
    Es wurde kein Transaktionsfehler festgestellt.

WARNUNGEN
    * Das Manifest für diese Anwendung enthält keine Signatur. Signaturüberprüfung wird ignoriert.

FORTSCHRITTSSTATUS DES VORGANGS
    * [16.10.2018 17:27:28] : Die Aktivierung von D:\Users\...\Desktop\....dsac wurde gestartet.
    * [16.10.2018 17:27:28] : Erforderliche Überprüfung auf Updates wird so ausgeführt, wie dies durch die Bereitstellung angegeben ist.
    * [16.10.2018 17:27:35] : Neue Aktualisierung wird verwendet
    * [16.10.2018 17:27:36] : Die Installation der Anwendung wurde gestartet.

FEHLERDETAILS
    Folgende Fehler wurden bei diesem Vorgang entdeckt.
    * [16.10.2018 17:27:40] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestParse)
        - Ausnahme beim Lesen des Manifests aus 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Drachenhorn-Team/Drachenhorn/publish/Application%20Files/Drachenhorn.Desktop_0_0_10_42/Drachenhorn.Desktop.exe.manifest': Das Manifest ist möglicherweise ungültig, oder die Datei konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
    - Quelle: System.Deployment
    - Stapelüberwachung:
        bei System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
        bei System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
        bei System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
        bei System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
        bei System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ConsumeUpdatedDeployment(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
        bei System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentUpdate(SubscriptionState& subState, String& errorPageUrl)
        bei System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ProcessOrFollowExtension(Uri associatedFile, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, String& errorPageUrl, TempFile& deployFile)
        bei System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)
        bei System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
        bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
        bei System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
        bei System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
    --- Interne Ausnahme ---
    System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestParse)
    - Das Analysieren und die DOM-Erstellung des Manifestes führten zu einem Fehler. Folgende Fehler wurden beim Analysieren protokolliert: 
        -HRESULT:   0x80070c81
         Anfangszeile:  0
         Anfangsspalte:     0
         Hostdatei:     
    - Quelle: System.Deployment
    - Stapelüberwachung:
        bei System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadCMSFromStream(Stream stream)
        bei System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest..ctor(FileStream fileStream)
        bei System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
    --- Interne Ausnahme ---
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
    - Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80070C81
    - Quelle: System.Deployment
    - Stapelüberwachung:
        bei System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IsolationInterop.CreateCMSFromXml(Byte[] buffer, UInt32 bufferSize, IManifestParseErrorCallback Callback, Guid& riid)
        bei System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadCMSFromStream(Stream stream)

DETAILS ZUR SPEICHERTRANSAKTION DER KOMPONENTE
    Es sind keine Transaktionsinformationen verfügbar.
```

Comment: I don't know German, but the source error is "Das Manifest ist möglicherweise ungültig, oder die Datei konnte nicht geöffnet werden." (The manifest may be invalid, or the file could not be opened.). I think the reason is because your publish service doesn't provide access to your application files. I did tried to check file available status for your executable file and dlll files and didnt had a luck. This is executable file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Drachenhorn-Team/Drachenhorn/publish/Application%20Files/Drachenhorn.Desktop_0_0_10_42/Drachenhorn.Desktop.exe

Comment: The File is availabel you need to access [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Drachenhorn-Team/Drachenhorn/publish/Application%20Files/Drachenhorn.Desktop_0_0_10_42/Drachenhorn.Desktop.exe.deploy](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Drachenhorn-Team/Drachenhorn/publish/Application%20Files/Drachenhorn.Desktop_0_0_10_42/Drachenhorn.Desktop.exe.deploy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have investigated your situation, and i can to say your problem is on host service. Because it gives wrong MIME Content-Type.

Here is your response http header:

[image: raw.githubusercontent.com]

As you can see you don't have any Content-Types from request, therefor browser starts download files as text and that's weird behavior, because i always have a download file pop message. But here is just raw text on the screen.

That's correct response from working enterprise application server with correct header:

[image: My example]

You can check server setup details here: [MIME Types for ClickOnce deployment](https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2010/06/12/mime-types-for-clickonce-deployment/)

I hope it was useful for you.

Comment: This seems to be the Issue. I am now trying to move to raw.githack.com.
But how could that be, that this works for more than a year and now it stops to work?
Maybe some updates for ClickOnce or Github?

Comment: I never had an experience with this host service, but it isn't any kind of ClickOnce update engine.